# Is there any known alg to fill certain area with rectangles of different size with most effective way?

Tags: algorithm

By "effective way" I understand "with leaving more usable free areas for other rectangles".

I translating some game and I need to rebuild it's font. Font area is limited to certain size. I need to effectively fill that area with `letters` and `letters combinations`.

My current cycle increases `X` by 1 until we can place newly letter by that coords. If `X` hit font's right border, my cycle makes X = 0, Y++;

It leaves blank areas that is possible to use (marked with red):
[image]

How to use free space more effective?

Like that (at least):
[image]

Comment: didn't understood clearly, why not append each letter successively to the right of previous one and when it hits right border go to next line left most position, not cool ?

Comment: @Vimal - this will result in same free spaces as current alg has, since rectangles can have different heights.

Comment: do these words contain some word or just some random letter's(it has some meaning they should be aligned properly) ? can you post some image where different height rectangles are there with letters and what and should not happen ?

Comment: @Vimal - `letters combinations` contains some meaning. And my picture shows exactly the problem of different height letter. In first line there is letter `Й` (before zero) that has height greater then others. Because of that all lower lines makes free spaces (they can't go a little lower to find a place for them. they go only from left to right). I will make new picture to show what I want.

Comment: Not clear what your problem is! Why (first example) your method does produce such a free space in the middle of the last line? ie: why i C not close to E ?! This is not related to letters width and should not be related to letters height.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - Because on upper line there is letter `Ы` that is single pixel lower than others. My alg test first `X`, then increase `Y`. Let's say `E` had coords `80,24` and size `7,8` Then we need to place `C`. We test line at `87,24` - no. We overlaps with lower pixels of `Ы`, then we test `88,24` - still not, still overlaps, `89,24` - no, no, no, no, `101,24` - YES! We no overlaps with anything anymore.

Comment: This looks similar to a bin-packing problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

You might try sorting the characters by some measure of their size and attempting to fit the largest first ('first fit decreasing'). There are no known non-exponential ways to get a perfect solution to this kind of problem in general, but some heuristics can get you very close in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the number of words in a row isn't very large(you said it's for some game). So you create a matrix say `wordInfo[numberOfRowsInDisplay][maximumNumberOfColumnsForAnyRowInDisplay]` you can calculate both of these variables by doing simple math like how many characters are in message(with width) and how many spaces(with width). It is filled as we go line by line and column by column for series of word/characters.

After that you for any `wordInfo[row][column]`, represents `width` and `height` of that word/character. So if you populating some row you just see where this word/character ends(some number, say, pixel for example) and now check in previous row what was greatest height in this region including partial overlaps, and than set height of this word/character accordingly in `wordInfo` matrix, which will help in plotting next row. (It would be more efficient if you just only 2 rows in matrix, u got it?)

Note : if number of rows is large and there are man different height characters than in some cases might completely change.

Comment: I don't clearly understand you answer, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: i will try adding code...but in simple words its like when you're adding a word at any place just see how much horizontal width you cover and now in that horizontal width see how up can you put this word which will be again based on what was deepest height word in previous line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I somewhat understand the basic idea.